# Zoomer in html5 in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in images which should zoom in and zoom out on touch like  [this](http://www.cartoonsmart.com/html5_zoomer.php5) . I used many examples from net like [this example](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) and i also used meta tag viewport. but i did not acheive the functionality which i required. I serached alot but did not find any desireable solution . any help regarding this issue.

At that time i am using meta tag but when i double touch on the image the image got smaller and not come to the orignal position.

```
    <meta name="viewport" 
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.25;, user-scalable=yes">
```

and from net i am using one css and js files of zoom but they also behave like same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that time i found a solution to this problem that is to use animate function and increase height ,width or individual height or width to accomplish zooming.

Here is my code that will zoom in and out image on mouse over:

```
     <h1>Image to Zoom In and Zoom Out</h1>

     <br />

      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XSHj67HnEzU/TviX8Jqe-hI/AAAAAAAABRQ        /Io5Ob6bYWq0/s1600
      /ShadowEffect.jpg" alt="image zoom in and out" title="image zoom with  jquery" id="image1">
     </img>
```

and in js:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
   $('#image1').width(200);

   $('#image1').mouseover(function()

   {

      $(this).css("cursor","pointer");

      $(this).animate({width: "300px"}, 'slow');

   });


$('#image1').mouseout(function()

  {   

      $(this).animate({width: "200px"}, 'slow');


   });
```

});